# Why is the tree tied to the ground?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

In B*lade Runner 2049*, the tree, where Officer obtains the chest of bones, is tied to the ground.

[image]

Why is the tree tied to the ground?

Comment: They're braces, designed to stop the tree falling over (or being uprooted in severe weather).

Comment: @delinear I second that. Please turn that into an answer and I'll promptly upvote.

Comment: @delinear [not to tell you how to suck eggs, but] You may want to point out that the _reason_ is that the world is messed up and 'natural' things don't really grow very well, so the tree needs the props.

Comment: the tree does not look alive to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That tree, along with most animals in the world of Blade Runner is dead and it's tied to the ground to prevent it from falling.

It's most likely an attempt by Sapper Morton to make it feel like a real farm by having a natural element which used to be pretty common in the old world.